# Converter caracter

Tags: c

```
char converte_minusculo (char *s) // porque esta errada
{
    int posicao = 0;
    while (s[posicao] != '\0')
    {
      if(s[posicao] >= 65 && s[posicao] <= 90)
        return s[posicao] + 32;
      else
          return s[posicao];
      posicao++;
    }
}
```

Não está me retornando nenhum valor;
também não sei se o tipo da função é essa mesma.
Eu preciso que volte os valores convertidos para o `main()`.

Comment: Se não está retornando nenhum valor, provavelmente não está entrando no while.

Comment: O que era suposto essa função fazer ? Converter uma string toda em minusculo ?

Answer (score 0):

```
char converte_minusculo (char *s[30])
{
    int posicao = 0;

    while (s[posicao] != '\0')
    {
        if(s[posicao] >= 65 && s[posicao] <= 90)
        {
            s[posicao] + 32;
        }

        posicao++;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Embora isso possa resolver o problema, incluir um comentário explicando a solução ou o que havia de errado é bem-vindo.

Answer (score 0):

```
void converte_minusculo(char s[]) {
    int posicao = 0;
    while (s[posicao] != '\0') {
        if (s[posicao] >= 'A' && s[posicao] <= 'Z') {
            s[posicao] = s[posicao] - 'A' + 'a';
        }
        posicao++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Embora a resposta possa resolver o problema, algum comentário explicando a solução seria bem-vindo.